# Is there a more efficient way to bring total .count() values of specific value on each row in Dataframe? (without merge, with lambda preferably)

Tags: python, pandas, lambda, pandas-groupby, apply

New here, my first post, please be patient :).

I want to add a new column in my df with the total count of contract number `["Child_contract"]` (is unique number) under `("Parent_contract")` (repeated number) on each row.

My below statement does the job, but it takes quite wile to process on my current df.

```
df["Total_count"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.groupby("Parent_contract")["Child_contract"].count().to_frame().loc[x["Parent_contract"]],axis=1)
```

Any reply's are much appreciated. Just to be clear I want to modify the df not filter it.

Comment: Why without a merge, and with a lambda?

Comment: Sorry, "without a merge", I mean copy the df, group it and then merge it back to the original df. A solution with lambda(but faster) or any other more performant ways of doing this. I have a really hard time to find something similar already posted. I find that merge take more lines of code, and I have a feeling that there is another way.. :)

Comment: @AdrianMolonfalean--I think you could speed up your solution by changing to the following: `fr = df.groupby("Parent_contract")["Child_contract"].count().to_frame();
df["Total_count"] = df.apply(lambda x: fr.loc[x["Parent_contract"]],axis=1)`.  Isn't is your current solution re-computes `fr` for each row although it is fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can speed up your current solution by changing to:

```
fr = df.groupby("Parent_contract")["Child_contract"].count().to_frame()
df["Total_count"] = df.apply(lambda x: fr.loc[x["Parent_contract"]],axis=1)
```

This provides >3X improvement in speed.

**Explanation**

- In your current solution
  df.groupby("Parent_contract")["Child_contract"].count().to_frame() is
  recomputed for each row.
- Precomputing and assigning to fr avoids
  this duplication of effort.

**Performance**

*Test Code*

```
from random import randint

def generate_data(min_rows):
    ' Generate dataframe with parent and child columns '
    parent_idx, child_idx = 1, 1

    d = {'Parent_contract':[],
         'Child_contract': []}

    while len(d['Parent_contract']) < min_rows:
      add = randint(1, 5)
      for _ in range(add):
          d['Parent_contract'].append(f"p{parent_idx}")
      parent_idx += 1
      for _ in range(add):
          d['Child_contract'].append(f"c{child_idx}")
          child_idx += 1
          
    return pd.DataFrame(d)

def posted_method(df):
    ' Posted method '
    df["Total_count"] = df.apply(lambda x: df.groupby("Parent_contract")["Child_contract"].count().to_frame().loc[x["Parent_contract"]],axis=1)
    return df
                                 
def suggested_method(df):
    ' Suggested Method '
    fr = df.groupby("Parent_contract")["Child_contract"].count().to_frame()
    df["Total_count"] = df.apply(lambda x: fr.loc[x["Parent_contract"]],axis=1)
    return df
```

*Timing* (using timeit)

```
nRows    Posted Method   Suggested Method   Speed Up
10        18.1 ms            6.37 ms          2.8
1,000     2.05 s             289 ms           7.1
10,000    1 min 5 s          3.01 s           21.5
```

Comment: Thank you @DarrylG for the elaborate answer!  This makes so much sense! I didn't see this. My computing time already improved. Thanks again.